# Use angular in laravel views

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

this is my firs question here but I`ve been trying to find a solution these days. I`m building a multi-page website and I`d like to use angular for front-end. I`ve seen most of the people have the issue of combining the angular syntax with laravel`s but I`d really like to know if it`s possible to include angular into one of laravel`s views without having to re-route to an angular.html page from angular directory.
Basically I want to know if there`s a way to use angular directly into "Route::get('test', 'Controller@getTest')" 
The problem is that when I set the response on the controller page( return view('pages.test')->with(array('1' => $1, '2' => $2)); ) the angular scope method gets the data as a whole and it`s hard to target the array 1 for example to use it in my AngularController
Hope this makes sense.... THanks in advance!

Comment: cast the array as an object    ->with((object) $array)

Comment: @user4621032 Tried this but I get Illegal offset type error when I load the view

Comment: var_dump the object in order to see how does it looks like and how do you access this object in the view